# How can I do something atfer validates fail from particular field in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a situation like that, I wanna check a field before save if it's a correct URL then save it, if not then change it to a correct way, my question is the validates function(regexp) is similar to Rails origin validates function, I don't wanna repeat it cause DRY principle, so is there any way can call the Rails validates alone?

I know I can do that by the way in below, but the syntax means check model with entire validates, so if other filed validate fail, it will change URL format, that's what I want, I wanna change URL format to correct format only when the URL format is not correct before save.

What's the best way to do it?

## The one way I think

```
  def set_url
    if self.valid?
      self.url = get_url_from_everywhere
    else
      self.url = "https://somedimain/#{get_url_from_everywhere.split('/').last}"
    end
  end
```

## My situition codebase

```
class Link < ApplicationRecord

  validates :url, format: { with: /\A(\A(http|https):\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,24}\/?\z/ix }

  before_save :set_url

  private

  def set_url
    if validates_url?(get_url_from_everywhere)
      self.url = get_url_from_everywhere
    else
      self.url = "https://somedimain/#{get_url_from_everywhere.split('/').last}"
    end
  end

  def get_url_from_everywhere
    "/xxx/ooo" #not a correct url
  end

  def validates_url?(url)
    #some regexp
  end
end
```

Comment: move callback to `before_validation` and remove validation itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test for the key `:url` in errors after you check if record is valid.

```
  def set_url
    valid?
    if errors.include?[:url]
      self.url = "https://somedimain/#{get_url_from_everywhere.split('/').last}"
    end
  end
```